# Finding polygons that are only partially overlapped by another polygon

Tags: qgis, arcgis-pro, overlapping-features, spatial-analysis

I've been trying to work through a problem using QGIS or ArcGIS (I have access to both). I have a Land Parcel layer (Polygon) and a Sewer Service Area layer (Polygon). Unfortunately, the Sewer Service Area layer hasn't been updated in a while to reflect the constant changes to the Land Parcel layer. These changes include subdivisions, land developments, and complete deletion or creation of new land parcels.

Because of this the Sewer Service Area layer doesn't neatly overlap the Land Parcel layer as it once did. Some land parcels have stayed the same. But some have not. My goal is to find the number of land parcels that are only PARTIALLY overlapped by the Sewer Service Area layer meaning that the parcel has been modified and the extent of the Sewer Service Area no longer covers it entirely. I don't want to run an intersect because that would pull up every land parcel overlapped by the Sewer Service Area layer. I'd imagine most of them are fine and would overlap 100% but I can visibly see some that aren't.

I don't need help fixing the data. I just need help figuring out how to find an accurate number of parcels that NEED to be fixed.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. By asking about multiple software stacks, you are in effect asking multiple questions. Since an Answer has been added for QGIS, you should probably [Edit] this to focus on QGIS.

Answer (score 3):

To select and count partially overlapping objects in QGIS you can use the Select By Location tool.
[image]

You can see the number of selected objects in the lower left corner of the screen:

[image]

Or by opening the layer attribute table:
[image]